# search view with the exact value

Tags: xpages

I have a view in which I search for products. I'm for example looking for product 1234.
The problem is their also exist products called 1234A and 1234 C etc. When I look with the code mentioned below I get all the items from product 1234 but also from 1234A and 1234 C etc.
It has to be limited to items from product 1234 only

Search code (under Data / Search in view results):

```
var tmpArray = new Array("");
var cTerms = 0;
if (sessionScope.SelectedProduct != null & sessionScope.SelectedProduct != "") {
tmpArray[cTerms++] = "(FIELD spareProduct = \"" + sessionScope.SelectedProduct +
"\")";
}
if (sessionScope.Development != null & sessionScope.Development != "") {
tmpArray[cTerms++] = "(FIELD spareStatus = \"*" + sessionScope.Development +
 "*\")";
}
qstring = tmpArray.join(" AND ").trim();
return qstring
```

Comment: A would recommend to use key search instead of full text search and use of parameter "Exact match".

Comment: Try this format for an exact search: [spareProduct] = "1234" (Assuming the database is full-text indexed).

Comment: @ Frantisek: I made a new sorted view and used key search with exact match , but the result is the same. When I look for 1234 I also get the items from 1234A etc..

Comment: @ Frantisek: Sorry it is working . My mistake. I only have to find a way now to have the possibility to search with more than one key ....

Comment: look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345143/xpages-filter-by-column-value-how-to-display-2-value-out-of-8-available-value

Comment: @Frantisek: Thanks . I combined the searched items in the view, so I can search for the combined items. Only problem I have now is that I have a special character ° in one of my fields.He doesn't select items with this character in it .... I don't seem to be able to use a ? in the key to search ?

Comment: How to remove the ° character at the end of a field in the column formula of a view ?

Comment: Found : @Word(FIELDNAME; "°" ; 1)

Comment: if it occurs anywhere in field value, use @ReplaceSubstring( field; "°"; "" )

Comment: please, post (rephrase your solution) and accept answer to your question - let's keep stackoverflow site tidy :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the suggestion from Frantisek :
I made a view with a combined column . (combined with the different "keys" I search for)
Then instead of using data / search , I used data/keys with exact keymatch. In this key I combined the searched items.
Since I had a field in wich I had sometimes at the end a character "°" , and it seems that this character doesn't work with a lookup , I took it out of my view and searched item with @Word(FIELDNAME; "°" ; 1). 
As Frantisek suggested I could have used @ReplaceSubstring( field; "°"; "" ) also.